# Hibernate mapping: one column to multiple tables

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I have a 'best practice' question for a scenario.

Scenario:
Multiple entities in a DB, for example, Document, BlogPost, Wiki can be shared by individuals. Instead of creating a share table for each entity, a single Share table is created. The issue is, how to map the share table with different entities?

I have three options, please advise which option is best, and if there is a better option.

**Option1:**
Create table Shares as:

```
SHARES  
id (unique)
entityId (non DB enforced FK to DOCUMENTS, WIKIS, POSTS etc.)
entityType
sharedBy
sharedWith
sharedDate
```

Here, entityId will be a FK to documentId, wikiId, postId etc. etc. and entityType will identity what type the entityId is.

This has issues in Hibernate modelling, when creating Share to entity mapping, such as share.getDocument() or share.getWiki() etc.

**Option 2:**
Create table Shares which only holds share information, and then create resolution tables that tie the share to the entity.

```
SHARES
id(PK)
sharedBy
sharedWith
sharedDate
shareType (helper field for searches)

SHARES_DOCUMENTS
share_id (unique ID and FK, one to one with SHARES)
document_id (FK to DOCUMENTS)

SHARES_POST
share_id (unique ID and FK, one to one with SHARES)
post_id (FK to POSTS)

more share tables here.
```

So, hibernate wise, Share can have one to one for each of the share types (like share.getDocument(), share.getPost(), and shareType will identify which relationship is 'active' )

**Option 3**
Similar to option 1, but create individual columns instead of entity id

```
SHARES
id (unique ID)
documentId (FK to DOCUMENTS, nullable)
postId (FK to POSTS, nullable)
wikiId (FK to WIKIS, nullable)
sharedBy
sharedWith
sharedDate
sharedType
```

Here, each column could be mapped to respective entity, but they are nullable. sharedType can identify which relationship is 'active'.

So, the question is , which practice is best, both database wise as well as hibernate mapping (and eventual querying, performance wise).

Thanks
M. Rather

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

Comment: Thanks, will look into this. But is this truly an inheritance issue? Or inheritance can be used to solve it. If each of the resolution tables had additional derivative information, then they could qualify for inheritance, but they just contain relationship to different entities. Also, most inheritance examples/documentation don't try to make a single column link to different entities. They truly have independent fields that define them further.

Comment: On a second thought, relationships to different entities do 'define them further'. I will look into multiple classes with single table option, and see how it works.

Comment: worked like a charm. This link is also helpful for how to use annotations for the inheritance mappings.. http://codeidol.com/java/netbeans/Entity-Inheritance/Single-Table-per-Class-Hierarchy/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by TheStijn, after looking into different ways to setup inheritance relationships, I went with 'Single Table per class hierarchy' approach, and ended up with the table like:

```
SHARES
---------
id PK
shared_by FK to User
shared_with FK to User
shared_Date
document_id nullable FK to Document
post_id nullable FK to Posts
... more ids here to link to more entities
type_discriminator (values, DOCUMENT, POST ... )
```

On Hibernate/Java side, 
One Share abstract class as...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SHARES")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE_DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Share {
    @Id
    @Column( name="ID", nullable=false )
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name="SHARED_BY", nullable=false )
    private User sharedBy;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name="SHARED_WITH", nullable=false )
    private User sharedWith;

    @Column(name="SHARED_DATE", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", nullable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date sharedDate;        
    ...

}
```

And two normal classes..

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DOCUMENT")
public class SharedDocument extends Share { 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name="DOCUMENT_ID", nullable=true )
    private Document document;
    ....

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("POST")
public class SharedPost extends Share {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name="POST_ID", nullable=true )
    private Post post;
    ....

}
```

As for usage, use the concrete classes only as:

```
@Test
public void saveNewDocumentShare(){
    SharedDocument sharedDocument = new SharedDocument();
    sharedDocument.setDocument(document1);
    sharedDocument.setSharedBy(teacher1);
    sharedDocument.setSharedWith(teacher2);
    sharedDocument.setSharedDate(new Date());

    sharedDocument.setCreatedBy("1");
    sharedDocument.setCreatedDate(new Date());
    sharedDocument.setModifiedBy("1");
    sharedDocument.setModifiedDate(new Date());


    SharedDocument savedSharedDocument = dao.saveSharedDocument(sharedDocument);

    assertNotNull(savedSharedDocument);
    assertThat(savedSharedDocument.getId(),notNullValue());
}

@Test
public void saveNewPostShare(){
    SharedPost sharedWikiPage = new SharedWikiPage();
    sharedPost.setPost(post1);
    sharedPost.setSharedBy(teacher1);
    sharedPost.setSharedWith(teacher2);
    sharedPost.setSharedDate(new Date());

    sharedPost.setCreatedBy("1");
    sharedPost.setCreatedDate(new Date());
    sharedPost.setModifiedBy("1");
    sharedPost.setModifiedDate(new Date());


    SharedPost savedSharedPost = dao.saveSharedPost(sharedPost);

    assertNotNull(savedSharedPost);
    assertThat(savedSharedPost.getId(),notNullValue());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a many-to-many relationship.

Default scenario for mapping those type of things is to use a separate table for connection information.
Something like:

```
table shared_connections {
    number owner_id
    ,number shared_id
}
```

All objects that are shareable should extend some basic class ex: AbstractSharedObject. (use @MappedSuperclass annotation and care about @Inheritance strategy).

and inside Individual class :

```
private Collection<AbstractSharedObject> shares;
```

map this collection as [ManyToMany](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join-m2m) relationship.

P.S. For this to work you will need to guarantee that the ids of all shareable objects are unique.