# Implementing Polymorphic Association in Java while using Hibernate ORM tool

Tags: java, hibernate

What I want to achieve is to have a model(entity) that can belong to more than one other model on a single association or multiple association in Java using Hibernate.

For example: Having a Phone_details entity that can belong to other entities such as Employee, Customer entities etc, but not explicitly have Employee_id and Customer_id's in the Phone_details entity.

From a Ruby On Rails background, it's usually implemented as follows:
Image Entity

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Other Entities can then be associated to this entity via **imageable**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :avatar, :class_name => "Image", :as => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Accommodation < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :pictures, :class_name => "Image", :as => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

How do I achieve this in Java using Hibernate.

Comment: just add another table that connects these - IIRC, this is the default strategy when having `@OneToMany` without a `@JoinColumn`

Comment: @Eugene thanks for the quick response, however, I don't quite get the picture, any similar implementation that you can share, code or perhaps even a site with the implementation, I have looked all over the internet but haven't seen anything quite like it...

Comment: simply create two entities with `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` and look at the generated tables - you will see one *extra* table that connects these two

Comment: here https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ is that what you are looking for? look at the first example

Comment: unfortunately, it isn't . The thing is, I want to have the Phone_details entity that can belong to any other entity, in the sense that, the Phone_details table will apart from it's other properties(fields) it should be able to hold a foreign key (fkey_id) as well as the the Type of the associating table... Meaning it's only after checking the type will it be known to which an instance of the Phone_details belongs to...

Comment: interesting... let me get this straight, so `phone_details` is a *single* table that will hold (among some other fields) a `fkey_id` (that could be either connected to instance1 or instance2) and a `type` that denotes what instance it is connected to?

Comment: yes, note: `fkey_id` denotes an instance of another entity ( It can be `Employee`, `Customer` or any other `Entity` in the DB that requires Phone_details).

Comment: you can probably achieve something like this via `@DiscriminatorColumn/@DiscriminatorValue`, but I can't tell for sure. I would re-think the strategy to handle this in the first place, if that would be an option

Comment: btw I think that this is exactly what you are looking for... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344731/hibernate-mapping-one-column-to-multiple-tables

Comment: @Eugene I checked the link and read even a bit more about `@DiscriminatorColumn, @DiscriminatorValue`, however using them entails extending of the Entity class in question, which doesn't fit in well because a single Entity may have to Extend more than one such Entity, whereas Java doesn't allow multiple extensions.

Comment: sorry, I am out of ideas :( but that looks like such a simple thing to do *without* any ORM

Comment: It's a situation, where I can have one single Entity responsible for `Phone_details` that any other Entity may have e.g `User`, `Customer` entities etc, either on a OneToOne or OneToMany (and or Vice-Versa) association, of which there could be another such Entity in the DB like `Image Entity` that could also belong the to same Entities as before for example User(as Avatar), Employee(as ID_Photo) or Item(as Item_image) Entity... Unless there is a clever way of implementing such using the `@Discriminator(Column/Value)`... I'm still stuck apparently...

Comment: @Eugene,  thanks for the effort, will try to look around the idea a little more harder and I should bet, something will come up!

Comment: You say without ORM, then how would the associations be persisted if not via an ORM? Is there another way w/o an ORM, I could check it out...

Comment: I was thinking simply in terms of select queries and if I understood you correctly this is a simple where with a join or two... again, if I dont miss something obvious